# C++ code for do Python struct.pack('>I',val)

Tags: c++, endianness

I have Python code `struct.pack('>I',val)` where `val` is any number, how can i do this in C++.

I know `struct.pack` return byte string in Big-endian byte-order in unsigned int, if set '>I', but how i do that in C++.

I understand that full analog of this function dosent exist in C++, but maybe i can do this with some C++ code? Thanks!

Comment: Lookup for the arpa/inet `ntohl()`, `htonl()` functions family ...

Comment: `htonl` will (where necessary) byte-swap a number and return another number, whereas `struct.pack` returns a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html), `struct.pack('>I',val)` converts a 32-bit unsigned integer into a string in big-endian format. The equivalent C++ code is straightforward to implement using bit operators and would typically look like this:

```
std::string pack_uint32_be(uint32_t val) {
    unsigned char packed[4];
    packed[0] = val >> 24;
    packed[1] = val >> 16 & 0xff;
    packed[2] = val >> 8 & 0xff;
    packed[3] = val & 0xff;
    return std::string(packed, packed + 4);
}
```

You can find a plethora of existing functions that convert between different endianness, but none of them in standard C++. For example, the [`htonl`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/htonl.html) function, shipped with implementations of BSD networking and standardized by POSIX, returns a number whose in-memory representation is the big-endian version of the given value. Using `htonl`, `pack_uint32_be` could be implemented as:

```
std::string pack_uint32_be(uint32_t val) {
    uint32_t packed_val = htonl(val);
    auto packed_ptr = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&packed_val);
    return std::string(packed_ptr, packed_ptr + 4);
}
```

Both functions assume inclusion of `<string>` for `std::string` and `<cstdint>` (or equivalent) for `uint32_t`. The latter function also requires inclusion of `arpa/inet.hr` or its Windows equivalent for `htonl`.